# Custom twitter timeline widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

Is it possible to customize somehow the new twitter widget apart from the predefined options given on the site? https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new

I would like to change some colors, delete the border, add some other images etc.

I would prefer not to use the Twitter Stream API because of the limited number of access per hour using the [user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) function. I would have to implement a cache system and complicate a bit more the things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change that. I think they restricted that to the Twitter Developers alone and therefore you can't customize it farther. I think you can only change the size of the widget alone.